# How can I alter a connector with ksqldb once it has been already created?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

Once I have a connector created by using the ksqldb expression `CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR...`, how can I make changes with ksqldb? Is there a way to alter the initial definition? Something like `ALTER CONNECTOR...`? If not, what is the proper way to handle changes in connectors with ksqldb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Connect is stateless, so it's safe to run DROP + CREATE CONNECTOR with new config

Comment: Is there any side effect as a consequence? F.ex it would start again from the beginning of binary log and send again all the messages?

Comment: No. Sink connectors store offsets in consumer offsets topic. Only if you rename the connector, it'll have default behavior of starting at the end of the topic

Comment: The problem that I've identified by dropping and creating the connector is the usage of a table.include.list (a white list). If you add a new table to the list in the second connector generation (after the drop) topic is not created. If I'm not wrong, even if you create the topic manually it won't be connected with the DB changes.

Comment: That is connector implementation dependent. Sounds like you're referring to JDBC source?  If so, look at `table.poll.interval.ms` property description

Comment: I'm using Debezium MySQL CDC connector. Maybe in order to avoid that problem (and downtimes) by dropping and creating the connector, a more efficient way instead removing could be just create a new connector with the new tables added to the whitelist. What do you think?

Comment: Maybe, but you do not want overlapping whitelists. Otherwise, you get duplicate records.

Comment: https://debezium.io/blog/2021/10/07/incremental-snapshots/ It could be a solution but I think it's only available for Debezium.